# How to make matplotlib show all x coordinates?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

For example in the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = np.random.rand(N)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I get the following plot

[image]

as you can see, in the x axis, only the even values appear. How to force matplotlib to show all values, that is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`?

Comment: By "all values" do you mean "all values in the input set" or "all integers in the input range"?  For instance, if your passed x values `[1, 2.3, 5.2]`, would you want to see 1, 2.3 and 5.2 on the x axis, or 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6?

Comment: I would want to see, 1 2.3 and 5.2

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use `plt.xticks(x)`.  See [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks).

Note that using only the input values for ticks will usually be confusing to a viewer.  It makes more sense to use evenly spaced ticks.

Answer (score 3):

Setting xticks using the values that are not evenly spaced makes a "bad" plot sometimes. For example, in the following case:

```py
x = [1,2.9,3.1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = np.random.rand(10)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xticks(x);
```

the x-tick labels are unreadable at some points.

[image: res1]

It's better if the tick labels are evenly spaced:

```py
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xticks(range(min(x), max(x)+1));
```

[image: res2]

FYI, you can get the limits of an axis by calling `plt.xlim()` or `plt.ylim()` so that you can set more accurate tick labels. Also, with `plt.xticks()` (and `plt.yticks()`), you can set arbitrary tick labels. For example, instead of numbers, tick labels could be strings (e.g. `a`, `b`, `c`).

```py
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.xticks(range(min(x), max(x)+1));
ymin, ymax = plt.ylim()   # (0.19667230980587072, 1.0097016485006163)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(0, 1, 4), ['0', 'a', 'b', 'c']);
plt.ylim(ymin, ymax);
```

[image: res3]

The very same graph can be plotted by explicitly creating subplots and setting the properties of the Axes object as well.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,2))
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set(xticks=np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1), yticks=np.linspace(0, 1, 4), yticklabels=['0', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ylim=ax.get_ylim());
```