# Matplotlib matshow: show all tick labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to Matplotlib and I created a Heatmap of some number's correlation using the `matshow`  function. Currently the code below only displays every 5th label (or tick), and I want it to display all of it. The code:

```
names = list('ABCDEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU')

#just some random data for reproductability
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 22)), columns=names)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

cor_matrix = df.corr()

#these two lines don't change the outcome
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(names)))
ax.set_yticks(list(range(0,len(names))))

ax.matshow(cor_matrix)
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

I read this question: [How to display all label values in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131822/how-to-display-all-label-values-in-matplotlib)
But the answer there didn't work for me. The figure doesn't change if I don't set the ticks explicitly, or set them either way.

Also tried this questions's solution: [How to make matplotlib show all x coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506907/how-to-make-matplotlib-show-all-x-coordinates)
Which was `plt.xticks(list(range(0,len(names))))`, but that didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the matplotlib functions is causing the issue. By calling `ax.matshow(cor_matrix)` after the assignment of the x- and y-ticks they are overwritten again. By changing the ordering, everything should just work fine.

***New order:***

```py
names = list('ABCDEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU')

#just some random data for reproductability
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 22)), columns=names)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

cor_matrix = df.corr()


ax.matshow(cor_matrix)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(names), step=1))
ax.set_yticks(list(range(0,len(names))))

plt.show()
```

***Output:***

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `MultipleLocator`:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator  # <- HERE

names = list('ABCDEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU')

#just some random data for reproductability
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 22)), columns=names)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

cor_matrix = df.corr()

ax.matshow(cor_matrix)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))  # <- HERE
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))  # <- HERE
plt.show()
```

[image: heatmap]

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I actually tried that as well, but I put it before the `ax.matshow(cor_matrix)` line, and that way it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes because `matshow` modify the x and y axis. So you have to override its settings after the plot function.

Comment: When I put `ax.matshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.7)` after ` ax.xaxis.set_major_locator` it did not work; just a note for others

Comment: @AlexPunnen. This doesn't work because `ax.matshow` resets the figure, so you need to customize the settings AFTER it's created.