Problem with making all values ​on the horizontal line in the graph in matplotlib?
I have a problem: This code creates a graph but does not show the names of all the values. What is wrong here?

year_counts = bi['year'].value_counts()

top_12= year_counts.nlargest(12)  


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
bars = plt.bar(top_12.index, top_12.values, color='skyblue')

for bar, percentage in zip(bars, year_percentages):
    height = bar.get_height()
    plt.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width() / 2, height, f'{percentage:.2f}%', ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')

plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Bar Graph of Top 12 Year Counts with Percentages')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


enter image description here What's the solution
for this problem?

Just adding the tick positions: plt.xticks(top_12.index, rotation=45, ha='right') should work.

.. Or increase rotation, or increase plot width

Does this answer your question? How to display all label values in matplotlib or https://stackoverflow.com/q/28506907/12846804

Welcome to S0! Please make sure to search for previous related answers before posting your own question. If you have, please indicate how what you found is not suitable in your case.
